How to Calculate Weight Distribution of Different Types of Chocolates in Irregular Containers
I am working on a problem involving the allocation of different types of chocolates within irregularly shaped containers. Specifically, I have containers that are difficult to measure directly, and I want to determine the weight distribution of multiple types of chocolates within these containers.
Here's a breakdown of my problem:
I have irregularly shaped containers, making it challenging to calculate their volume directly.
Each container can be filled with different types of chocolates, each with its own price per pound and density per pound.
I want to calculate how much weight (in pounds) of each type of chocolate is present in each container.
Importantly, not all sections of the container may be fully filled with chocolates, and the filled portion may vary.
I'm looking for a method or algorithm that allows me to:
Distribute this total weight among different types of chocolates based on their densities.
Accommodate variations in the filling level of each container section.
Could someone provide guidance or suggest an approach to tackle this problem effectively? Any relevant mathematical principles or programming techniques would be greatly appreciated.
What I know is:

The density of the chocolate lbs.- per cubic inch
the current weight if the container filled with assorted chocolates (- the tare of the container)


I'm confused.  Part of the question talks about the goal being to measure the weight (which makes me think it is already assigned and we can't change it).  Part of it talks about distributing the weight (which makes me think we can choose it).  Which is it?  Please [edit] the question to make it clearer what you're asking.  I suggest you list all the quantities are known (define mathematical notation and be precise; I don't know what "The density of the chocolate" means - which chocolate?), list what quantities you want to infer/select.
